# Thread & Windows forms

Tags: c#, controls, multithreading

I'd like to know if the executing thread is the one that created a given control instance (to prevent cross-thread if it's not). 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check for control.InvokeRequired flag. if it is true, use the control.Invoke function to perform the operation.

Here is an article which looks in to the different scenarios in detail:
http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/articles/126345.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea also to set Control::CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to true in the beginning of the program, to get predictable crash in the case of incorrect cross-thread call.

Answer (score 0):

A great article (in my opinion) is the one available at http://www.albahari.com/threading/. It goes over all that you need to know about threading in C#, from Mutex to lock to [Control.Invoke](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Apartments_and_Windows). I myself came from the Java world, and thought that C# threads and synchronization was the same, but this web page set me straight. :-)